# Driving sensorless three phase BLDC motor with Arduino and IMU

Tags: arduino, control, motor, brushless-motor

I have started to work on a little project of mines, which consists in implementing the stabilization a single axis gimbal using Arduino.

The gimbal is driven by a sensorless three phase brushless DC (BLDC) motor, while on it's shaft there is a generic payload provided with an IMU board (3 axes gyros + 3 axes accelometers), which can give feedback to the Arduino about the angular rates and accelerations.

[image]

I have googled a bit about this topic and there are so many solutions out there, the only thing I really do not understand is about the control of the BLDC motor.

1. Can I use a sensorless control of the motor, by sensing the back EMF
   even if the motor is spinning very low?
2. How can I energize properly the phases of the BLDC motor if it is sensorless?
3. Can I use the IMU for finding out how to spin the BLDC motor properly without counter rotations?

Could you give me any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

consider coupling the motor with an encoder that has enough resolution to tell you precisely when to ramp up current to a particular phase. this will give you precise feedback to develop a control loop that should give maximum torque for a given voltage.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use any encoder as it introduces extra costs to the whole system.

Comment: i found this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3231115/

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to adding components to the power circuit? If you add in a portion that measures current being drawn by the motor, you can get some decent feedback about what the motor is doing and how much of a mechanical load is being applied to it.

Comment: It isn't that I'm opposed in adding components, the point is that I would like to achieve my goal by using what I currently have. Maybe in the future I would add current sensors.

Comment: That's reasonable. I'm just a big fan of the current sensing method to get a quick 'status' of a motor.